# how to get selected items in telerik radlistview

Tags: winforms, telerik

With normal winform controls I would do something like this:

```
        ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection col = listView1.SelectedItems;

        foreach (ListViewItem item in col)
        {
            label8.Text = item.SubItems[1].Text;
            label9.Text = item.SubItems[3].Text;
        }
```

but I cant seem to create the samething with telerik radlistview, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do something similar with radlistview. The class you need to use is Telerik.WinControls.UI.ListViewDataItem.

```
    Telerik.WinControls.UI.ListViewSelectedItemCollection col = listView1.SelectedItems

    foreach (ListViewDataItem item in col)
    {
        label8.Text = item[1].ToString();
        label9.Text = item[3].ToString();
    }
```

I'm not sure if the ToString() is necessary. I tried it without the ToString(), and it worked fine for me, but my objects are strings.

Answer (score 0):

Following [Telerik Documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/listview-programatically-populating-with-data.html)

You can choose one of three methods to get or set values in subitems of RadListView:
- by using the column index
- by using the column name
- by using a column reference

Examples:

```
 item[0] = "CellValue1";
 item["Column2"] = "CellValue2";
 item[radListView1.Columns[2]] = "CellValue3";
```